# unable to load window after adding confirmation for delete

Tags: android

i just added a confirmation message for deleting a contact in android
there is no any error on my code but when i click on the delete button, the program shut down and give me following error.

```
> 03-27 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 03-27 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):
> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
> token null is not for an application 03-27 04:30:32.309:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
> 03-27 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
> 03-27 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281) 03-27 04:30:32.309:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> com.example.android.ViewDetail$1.onClick(ViewDetail.java:95) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202) 03-27 04:30:32.309:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-27 04:30:32.309:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-27 04:30:32.309:
> E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
> 03-27 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 03-27
> 04:30:32.309: E/AndroidRuntime(1855):     at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is the part that i just added and cause the error.

```
//delete button
        deleteb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getBaseContext());

                    // set title
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent (ViewDetail.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("deleteButton","delete");
                                intent.putExtra("ContactID",getContactID);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                ViewDetail.this.finish();
                            }
                          })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                });
```

can somebody help me with this?

Eddited. This is my MainActivity page

```
package com.example.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;    
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    abcDBHelper xHelper;
    ListView lv;
    Button btnAdd;
    List<Contact> getAllContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //portarait mode
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PORTRAIT MODE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
         }
        //landscape mode
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LANDSCAPE MODE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
         }

        Button addNew = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        addNew.setOnClickListener(this);

        xHelper = new abcDBHelper(this);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

        Bundle passData;
        //button click to execute following function
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("deleteButton"))
        {
            onClickDelete();
        }
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("createButton"))
        {
            onClickInsert();
        }



        getAllContact = getAllContact();
        List<String> showList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i= 0; i<getAllContact.size(); i++){
            showList.add(getAllContact.get(i).getFullName());

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,showList);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);      

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id){
                long ContactID = getAllContact.get((int)id).getContactID(); 
                onClickSelect(ContactID);
            }
    });

}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //show contact
    public List<Contact> getAllContact(){

         List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
         SQLiteDatabase db;
         String cmd;

         db = xHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM detail;", null);
         while(cursor.moveToNext()){

             int ContactID     = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
             String FamilyName = cursor.getString(1);
             String FirstName  = cursor.getString(2);
             int HouseNumber   = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
             String Street     = cursor.getString(4);
             String Town       = cursor.getString(5);
             String Country    = cursor.getString(6);
             String Postcode   = cursor.getString(7);
             int Telephone     = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8));

             Contact newContact = new Contact(ContactID,FamilyName,FirstName,HouseNumber,Street,Town ,Country ,Postcode,Telephone);
             contacts.add(newContact);
         }
        return contacts;    

    }

   //insert new contact to database
    public void onClickInsert() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        String cmd;
        db = xHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String getFamName  = bundle.getString("dbFamilyName" );
        String getFirName  = bundle.getString("dbFirstName" );
        int    getHouseNo  = bundle.getInt   ("dbHouseNumber" );
        String getStreet   = bundle.getString("dbStreet"  );
        String getTown     = bundle.getString("dbTown"    );
        String getCountry  = bundle.getString("dbCountry" );
        String getPostcode = bundle.getString("dbPostcode");
        int    getTelNo    = bundle.getInt   ("dbTelephone"   );
        //insert
        ContentValues pStatement = new ContentValues();
        pStatement.put  ("dbFamilyName",getFamName);
        pStatement.put  ("dbFirstName",getFirName);
        pStatement.put   ("dbHouseNumber",getHouseNo);
        pStatement.put   ("dbStreet",getStreet);
        pStatement.put  ("dbTown",getTown);
        pStatement.put  ("dbCountry",getCountry);
        pStatement.put   ("dbPostcode",getPostcode);
        pStatement.put   ("dbTelephone",getTelNo);
        db.insert("detail",null,pStatement);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        xHelper.close();

    }
    //delete contact
    public void onClickDelete() {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = xHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Bundle bundle =getIntent().getExtras();
        int ContactID = bundle.getInt("ContactID");



        db.delete ("detail","_id"+" = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(ContactID)} );
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        xHelper.close();


    }

    //select clicked contact
    public void onClickSelect(long ContactID) {
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        String cmd;
        db = xHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM detail WHERE _id = "+ContactID, null);
        String Result = "";

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

         int  ContactID2       = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
         String FamilyName = cursor.getString(1);
         String FirstName  = cursor.getString(2);
         int HouseNumber   = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3));
         String Street     = cursor.getString(4);
         String Town       = cursor.getString(5);
         String Country    = cursor.getString(6);
         String Postcode   = cursor.getString(7);
         int Telephone     = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8));

        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,ViewDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("dbContactID", ContactID2);
        intent.putExtra ("dbFamilyName", FamilyName);
        intent.putExtra ("dbFirstName", FirstName);
        intent.putExtra ("dbHouseNumber", HouseNumber);
        intent.putExtra ("dbStreet", Street);
        intent.putExtra ("dbTown", Town);
        intent.putExtra ("dbCountry", Country);
        intent.putExtra ("dbPostcode", Postcode);
        intent.putExtra ("dbTelephone", Telephone);
        startActivity(intent);

        Result += (ContactID2);       
        }
        cursor.close();
        xHelper.close();
    }

  //SQLiteOpenHelper    
    class abcDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public abcDBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "user_info.db", null, 2);
            Log.d("Database Operation","Databse created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// create table
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE detail (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dbFamilyName TEXT, dbFirstName TEXT , dbHouseNumber INTEGER, dbStreet TEXT, dbTown TEXT, dbCountry TEXT, dbPostcode TEXT, dbTelephone INTEGER);");
            Log.d("Database Operation","Table created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS detail");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    // navigate
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.add){
            Intent a = new Intent (MainActivity.this, CreateContact.class);
            startActivity(a);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace getBaseContext(); with  >> "this"

Comment: changed, and it give me  "The constructor  alertdialog.builder new view.onclicklistener is undefined

Comment: Try to send your activity's instance. For example if your activity name is MainActivity thy this:

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
or:

AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

Comment: thanks! (v.getContext()); works! can u briefly explain why v.getContext works instead of mainActivity?

Comment: Most welcome.. please help other by accepting answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the context

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getBaseContext());
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        ViewDetail.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

An Activity Context is missing your AlertDialog thats why token is null

if you use in fragment  means call like

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```